# Mysql and between\in range condition

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, between

We have x2 columns `min` and `max`. Each can be `null` or `integer`. When we start search throw table we cannot use BETWEEN command... Question is, how to find in range with this conditions

1. `value` is greater then `min` (if it's not null)

and

2. `value` is less then `max` (if it's not null)

and

3. `value` is in range of `min` and `max` (if they BOTH not null)

`value` - our integer number. As you can see we cannot use BETWEEN command.

Comment: Why can;t you use `BETWEEN`? If `value` is null then it won't be greater/less-than and won't meet the conditions; so forget that it could be null.

Answer (score 2):

So NULL means no limit. You can still use `BETWEEN`:

```
select *
from mytable
where @value between coalesce(minvalue, @value) and coalesce(maxvalue, @value);
```

Or simply `AND`:

```
select *
from mytable
where @value >= coalesce(minvalue, @value) 
  and @value <= coalesce(maxvalue, @value);
```

Or the very basic `AND` and `OR`:

```
select *
from mytable
where (@value >= minvalue or minvalue is null)
  and (@value <= maxvalue or maxvalue is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
WHERE col BETWEEN COALESCE(min, -2147483648) AND COALESCE(max, 2147483647)
```

According to your logic, if either the `min` or `max` be `NULL`, then the restriction should be ignored.  In the above `WHERE` clause, if `min` be `NULL` then `col` will always be greater than the lower boundary, assuming that `col` is an integer.  Similar logic applies to the `max` condition.

The large (and small) numbers you see represent the largest and smallest possible values for an integer in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Without the option of using `BETWEEN`, I would recommend using a simple `WHERE-AND` clause.

If null values are not allowed, you should use the `COALESCE` function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
SELECT * 
FROM SCORES
WHERE score >= COALESCE(min_score, score)
AND score <= COALESCE(max_score, score)
```

Here is a sample fiddle I created

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/306947/2/0

Answer (score 0):

My solution Yii2 AR like

```
    $query
        ->joinWith(['vacancySalary'])
        ->andWhere([
            'and',
            'IF (vacancy_salary.min IS NULL, ' . $this->salaryMin . ', vacancy_salary.min) >= ' . $this->salaryMin,
            'IF (vacancy_salary.max IS NULL, ' . $this->salaryMin . ', vacancy_salary.max) <= ' . $this->salaryMin
        ]);
```

Simple answer is use IF condition and proper values.

ADDED:
Another way to go

```
$query
    ->joinWith(['vacancySalary'])
    ->andWhere($this->salaryMin . ' BETWEEN IF(vacancy_salary.min IS NULL, 0, vacancy_salary.min) AND IF(vacancy_salary.max IS NULL, 0, vacancy_salary.max)');
```